# How to call member variable in parent of outerClass from annonymous InnerClass

Tags: java, inheritance, anonymous-inner-class

I have *OuterClass* extends *ParentClass*.
I'm trying to override *annonymous InnerClass* of *ParentClass* in *OuterClass*, and what I want to do is to call the member variable of *ParentClass* inside the overrided *annonymous InnerClass*.
Here is my code:

```java
class ParentClass {
    int a;
    Runnable act;
    ParentClass() {
        act = new Runnable() {
            void run() {
                //codes
            }
        }
    }
}

class OuterClass extends ParentClass {
    OuterClass() {
        super();
        super.act = new Runnable() {
            void run() {
                // I want to call 'int a' here!!!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: you can make it (the variable you want to access) protected, create a getter (`get` method) for the variable) with protected or public access...

Comment: However, looking at your code, the `Runnable` object you are creating there is not related to the `ParentClass` - neither to `OuterClass`... This might be your issue here. You might want to create a class that implements `Runnable` and that has a constructor that receives the variable you want

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado, what do you mean by "the Runnable object you are creating there is not related to the ParentClass -neither to OuterClass"?

Comment: I rather suggest you declare "act" to be protected (read about that keyword) and simply access it directly. Or you make it private, but a protected setter method for it.

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado Ah, I understand. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @GhostCat, but how can I access it directly? I tried "a", "super.a", "ParentClass.this.a" but didn't work...

Comment: I suggest you stop wasting your time with. Focus on doing things the right way. Research the usage of protected, instead of trying to use something that isn't intended to be used that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do the trick for you:

```java
class ParentClass {
    protected int a;
    protected Runnable act;
    ParentClass() {
        act = new Runnable() {
            void run() {
                //codes
            }
        }
    }
}

class OuterClass extends ParentClass {
    OuterClass() {
        super();
        super.act = new RunnableClass (a);
    }
}

class RunnableClass implements Runnable {
    private int a;
    public RunnableClass(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void run() { //--- the code here
    }

}
```

I'm not sure if using `protected`is the best approach as access rights for you, but my goal here is to let you free to create your own `Runnable`, with everything you need.

Comment: Now I fully understand!! Thank you very much for your help :)